# Как реализовать радиальный прогресс бар?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как можно реализовать радиальный прогрес бар , так чтоб например  при клике на круг закрашивалась та часть круга которая до клика, и в перемененную попадал процент закрашенного круга ?

Вот как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятна задача.

Как правило различные прогресс бары уже получают какое-нибудь value, согласно которому закрашивают область загрузки. Т.е. этот value и есть Ваша переменная.

Насчет смены цвета:
[Вот](https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress) тут цвет задаётся через атрибут fill, изменяйте его при клике так, как вам необходимо и получите желаемое.

Мой пример очень локален, библиотек, позволяющих создавать различные прогресс бары очень много.